# Is it possible for home-assistant to send data via RestAPI to my backend source?

Tags: home-assistant

Data from sensors are sending to my Home Assistant.

I want to perform some analysis on those data. So I am thinking if there is anyway to have the Home Assistant sending data to my backend via Rest API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Node Red add-on should be what you are looking for.